# Android : Bitmap : From parcel : Out of memorry exception

Tags: android, bitmap

I am using a bundle to send a bitmap from one application to another.
And i retrieve the bitmap from the bundle for use in a different application.
**The specific use of bundle was necessary in this place.**

And when i read it out i get a OUT OF MEMORY EXCEPTION.

```
bitmap = (Bitmap)receivedmsg.getData().getParcelable("myobject");
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: try with increasing the inSamplesize of the bitmap. Before passing to anther activity.

Comment: Can you post all your code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means what it says. The image you serialized is too big to be read back into memory in the other app. The fastest fix is what M Mohsin Naeem alludes to: you need to make the image smaller! Do so in the app that sends the image. For example, if that app is reading from a file, you can set it to down-sample the image to a smaller size.

Also consider whether you really need to send the image this way, or whether you could save it to the SD card, and then process it without reading into memory.